# Why is there a measurement problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, measurement-problem

From what I understand, the measurement problem seems to be a problem of humans limitations and nothing more. It seems to be pretty egocentric.

We're saying, because we can only observe one probable state after measurement, the whole wavefunction or whatever the wavefunction represents must collapse. What if we just can't observe the wavefunction or whatever it represents in it's entirety? Maybe it's multidimensional and from our 3D perspective we can only observe one of it's probable states after measurement.

Maybe Godel's Incompleteness applies here and we just can't know the complete truth about the nature of the wavefunction or what it represents. Am I missing something here?

Exactly what is there to clarify? People are responding to the question just fine and having a debate. Why close the question for no reason?

Comment: You are missing the meaning of Godel's theorem.

Comment: The idea that there is still an uncollapsed wavefunction unbeknownst to us is widely believed today. But the mnemonic for this appeals to extra worlds rather than extra dimensions.

Comment: "we just can't know the complete truth about the nature of the wavefunction or what it represents." -- this is not the measurement problem. Nobody is hung up on some sophomoric idea of "knowing the complete truth of the nature of the wavefunction". The easurement problem is a rather specific and precise question.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, your arguments anyway don't deny the measurement problem, so you are just asking why people don't give up because man, it would be so arrogant to think we can understand stuff?

Answer (score 8):

In broad strokes, the standard formulation of quantum mechanics includes two types of time evolution for the system - *unitary* evolution, which is governed by the Schrodinger equation (or something equivalent), and *projective* evolution, which occurs when a measurement is made. The former is completely deterministic, while the latter is intrinsicially probabilistic.

The predictive framework which arises from this is self-consistent and accurately describes many experiments.  However, at the meta level it is deeply problematic, because there's really no clear sense of what constitutes a measurement.  This leaves physics open to claims from peddlers of [quantum woo](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Quantum_woo) that the key ingredient of projective evolution (i.e. that which makes something a measurement) is the observation of the system by a human consciousness.

For those of us who are less interested in selling you crystals, this leads to the measurement problem. What constitutes a measurement, and what is it about a measurement which induces probabilistic, projective evolution rather than deterministic, unitary evolution?

For many people (myself included), the most plausible resolution to the puzzle involves recognizing that a measurement apparatus - which may include a human being - is **itself** a quantum system.  There are other interpretations which resolve or reframe the problem in different ways, but each opens the door to additional questions, so the issue is far from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a single particle that, for an experiment, is prepared in a way that it is in a superposition of two states, e.g. the usual suspect spin up or down. When, after this preparation, the spin is measured, the outcome of the measurement is either up or down.

But if we measure the spin of the same particle a second time shortly afterwards, the spin will always be identical to the one of the first measurement. Thus it *looks like* as if the first measurement has modified the wave function such that it represents only one state, not the superposition of two states anymore. This is called collapse.

Note that I said “looks like”. The term “collapse” represents an *interpretation* of this experimental fact. It is called the measurement *problem* because nobody is very happy with this interpretation because the details of this collapse are completely mysterious.

(BTW Gödel has nothing to do with this lack of understanding)
The measurement problem reminds us of some basic lack of understanding of the inner workings of QM. This doesn’t mean that QM doesn’t work: we know perfectly well how to do the mathematics of QM. The problem is the lack physical understanding of *why* the mathematical model works.

Comment: How long do you have to make a second measurement and get the same result as the first measurement?

Comment: Where is the mystery. You take the time to correlate the spins of two particles. Then you measure one of them. Why is it a surprise that you could know the spin of the other particle automatically? You started the experiment by correlating them to be the same. There’s no mystery or surprise because they should be the same.

Comment: @BillAlsept Hi Bill, I believe you are misinterpreting Hartmut’s thought experiment - they are referring to two subsequent measurements of the same particle, not a pair of entangled particles. The takeaway - which you may view as obvious - is that one cannot measure a system without altering its state in the process; this differs from classical physics, in which one usually tacitly assumes that a measurement of some property of the system can in principle be performed sufficiently gently as to not influence its state.

Comment: @BillAlsept The additional point at the core of the measurement problem is that - at least naively - the evolution of the state which occurs during the process of a measurement is distinctly different from the ordinary evolution which occurs in-between measurements, most crucially because it is apparently non-deterministic. Why this should be is the essence of the measurement problem, to which there are a number of proposed solutions. Based on our previous interactions I would guess that your preferred resolution is the "hidden variable" approach, which loosely says that evolution [...]

Comment: [...] is *always* deterministic, but that we simply didn't know all of the properties of the pre-measurement state. Because we lacked this extra information, the measurement process appears non-deterministic. The problem with this approach, and the reason it is rejected by most physicists, is that [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) demonstrates that any hidden variable theory which resolves the measurement problem must be non-local. Still, such non-local theories exist - see e.g. [de Broglie-Bohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory).

Comment: @J.Murray I edited the answer a bit to avoid the possible misunderstanding you pointed at. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Murray But the only way to truly compare is to correlate two particles and send them to two testers and later measure one of them. If you are talking about one particle being measured twice there still is no mystery. An electron passing through a stern Gerlock Device will rotate according to the positioning of the device, If you measure it again with the device in the same position then of course it will be the same but if you rotate the device on the second measurement it will change accordingly. The device doesn’t just measure the particle it also influences it. No mystery in that.

Comment: @BillAlsept As I said, you may regard it as self-evident that the state of the system is invariably influenced by the measurement device. However, you still need to account for the ostensibly non-deterministic evolution that measurement seems to cause, hence my additional two comments.  As a side note, your interpretation of the SG experiment seems to assume that a classical dipole rotates to align itself with an applied magnetic field and then stops rotating, which isn't true unless there are additional influences at work.

Comment: @J.Murray I didn’t say the device completely aligns the spins, I said it influences them and we know this is true. I consider any of the experiments to be deterministic evolution which can be derived. There are no solutions for a nondeterministic evolution. It is possible to correlate two particles or objects and correlate them so that when you send them two separate testers you can measure one and know everything about the other one without measuring it. This could be done with the results that match all the predictions of quantum mechanics or Malus Law/ cos2theta

Comment: @BillAlsept But empirically it *does* completely align the spins, either parallel or antiparallel to the external field. That's why your analysis of the SG experiment doesn't hold up - there is simply no classical mechanism which would yield a 50/50 splitting with nothing in between. Your comments about entanglement are a separate issue, which I won't address here; I also do not mean to have a prolonged discussion in the comments of another user's answer. I wanted only to point out that to brush off the measurement problem as "obvious" is either overly hasty or at odds with empirical facts.

Comment: Could we take it to chat where are you can respond at your convenience?